# Operation counts of Algolia free plan

Tags: algolia

```
100,000
then paused
until renewal
```

Algolia pricing page contains a cell like this in it's free plan.

Does it mean after `100.000` operations customers should switch to a paid plan or is does it reset montly just like the others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your App reaches operation limit on a free plan, it won't be able to perform any extra call until the next renewal.

Thanks for your question, we should give more details on our pricing page.

Comment: Does the renewal happen each month?

Comment: it resets each month by the day of your signup, you can see details on this tab https://www.algolia.com/change_plan#?tab=invoices

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I am pretty sure that I can safely use Algolia for the application I am building!

Answer (score 0):

[They no longer have a limit.](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/accounts-billing/how-algolia-count-records-and-operation/)

> We don’t count indexing operations towards your usage for users on our current (starting July 2020) Free, Standard, and Premium plans. However, to prevent extreme numbers of operations impacting your cluster, we implemented a protective limit of 10,000 indexing operations per unit.